# как установить madelineproto на php7.3

Tags: php, composer, madelineproto

Как установить https://docs.madelineproto.xyz/ на php7.3

```
<?php

if (!file_exists('madeline.php')) {
    copy('https://phar.madelineproto.xyz/madeline.php', 'madeline.php');
}
?>
```

Этот код подходит только для php>=8.1 а мне нужно для php7.3.x

Comment: Судя по требованиям PHP 8.1+ is required. [https://docs.madelineproto.xyz/docs/REQUIREMENTS.html](https://docs.madelineproto.xyz/docs/REQUIREMENTS.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В этом году поддержка закончится ,но способ есть:

Качаем xampp с php 7.4+

```
php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"
php -r "if (hash_file('sha384', 'composer-setup.php') === '55ce33d7678c5a611085589f1f3ddf8b3c52d662cd01d4ba75c0ee0459970c2200a51f492d557530c71c15d8dba01eae') { echo 'Installer verified'; } else { echo 'Installer corrupt'; unlink('composer-setup.php'); } echo PHP_EOL;"
php composer-setup.php
php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');"
```

Ставим композер

Далее: перекидываем composer.phar в папку с кодом(где лежит index.php) и создаем фаил conposer.json

```
{
    "require": {
        "danog/madelineproto": "^7",
        "psr/log": "^1"
    },
    "config": {
        "allow-plugins": {
            "phabel/phabel": true
        },
        "platform": {
            "php": "7.4.1"
         }
    }
    
}
```

и в конце php composer.phar update

Comment: Вы уверены что на 7.4 библиотека будет корректно работаеть? Скорее всего версия 8.1 там указана не просто так.

Comment: У меня всё заработало!